# R - Network analysis with a point dataset (GPS data)

Tags: r, gps, cluster-analysis, igraph

I'm new to network analysis but I'm exploring this option for a study I'm conducting.

What I want to do is to detect clusters of points (from GPS data). I know there are multiple ways of doing so, with several R packages (e.g. `GPSeqClus`). However, it seems that most of them require *establishing a radius* (to then group the data, which makes sense to me).

Here's how my input dataset would look like:

```
id   datetime          lat    lon
A1   12/05/2018 12:00  47.369 17.326
A1   12/05/2018 17:00  47.371 17.328
A1   12/05/2018 21:00  47.373 17.331
A1   12/05/2018 23:00  47.381 17.385
A1   13/05/2018 02:00  47.392 17.391
```

And when plotted, where the red circle would be a cluster:

[image]

However, I was wondering whether there is a way of doing the same, but ***without** the need to specify the cluster radius*. While trying to answer this question, I came up with **network analyses**, which seem to be what I was looking for - from what I saw in [this tutorial](https://dshizuka.github.io/networkanalysis/05_community.html) for example, some groups are clearly defined and there is no need to specify any buffer.

But it looks like the input data is a matrix of some sort, by using the `make_graph` function from the `igraph` package ([source](https://dshizuka.github.io/networkanalysis/02_dataformats.html)). So **(1)** I'm wondering if this could be done with other data (GPS data, as the example shown above)?

When I apply the `make_graph` function to the example provided above (lat and lon values), I get this:

[image]

Which is basically just associating the `x` and `y` coordinates of each point... Any thoughts?

And also, **(2)** if network analyses do not work for this particular case (GPS data), does anyone know another option for grouping data without the need to establish a radius? Thanks in advance!

**EDITS:** focused a bit more the questions, and added an example of what my data looks like, with an example of a cluster (and what happens when I apply the `make_graph` function to my data)

Comment: To make this problem more tangible, I suggest adding an example and a first attempt.

Comment: Thanks! Just did that, let me know if I can add something else pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is primarily a problem of specifying your design and desired output and not a code-techinal question, but I'll write some code to help you direct your desired output.

There are pleny of clustering or classification algorythms that you can apply to your coordinates, and you don't need any graph theory for this. I would say that you should persue the network track only if it makes sense for a position which ties that can be asumed between your points in more than one degree.

Since you asked specifically for the networks, however, you should know that your graph outputs like that since you generated it in an unintended way, I think.

Lets load your example data into R and see where you probably miss-specified your graph:

```
library(igraph)

df <- data.frame(
    name = paste0('N',1:5),
    ts = as.POSIXlt(c('2018-05-12 12:00:00',
                      '2018-05-12 17:00:00',
                      '2018-05-12 21:00:00',
                      '2018-05-12 23:00:00',
                      '2018-05-13 02:00:00')),
    x = c(47.369,47.371,47.373,47.381,47.392),
    y = c(17.326,17.328,17.331,17.385,17.391)
)

# You should build the graph using NETWORK data, not a list of data-points.
# This is wrong:
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
plot(g)
# This is right, even though the graph is empty just here:
g <- make_empty_graph() %>% add_vertices(nrow(df), attr=list('name'=df$name))
plot(g)
```

The desired input format for `graph_from_data_frame()` is an edge list. Since your data only implicitly contains relevant network data we will first create an edge-list of a full graph (a graph where all nodes are connected), and then calculate a distance between them to use as a foundation for a cummunitty detection algorythm to base its clustering. Do pause mid-way to see how the data was transformed into a weighted edgelist.

```
# Build an edgelist using the combinations between all nodes
el <- combn(df$name, 2, simplify = TRUE) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename(i=V1, j=V2)

# This function calculates the pythagorean distance between points
pyth_dist <- function(node_1, node_2){
    x1 <- df$x[df$name == node_1]
    y1 <- df$y[df$name == node_1]
    x2 <- df$x[df$name == node_2]
    y2 <- df$y[df$name == node_2]
    
    # Pythagoras is our friend!
    sqrt((abs(x1-x2)^2) + (abs(y1-y2)^2))
}
# Apply to get distance between all nodes
el$dist <- apply(el[, c("i", "j")], 1, function(row) {
    pyth_dist(row[1], row[2])
}) * 100

# Look at this edge-list. This is what graph_from_data_frame() wants:
(el)

# Your graph recieves the third column as a weight. Each point is now connected
# with a weight equal to the pythagorean distance between it and its connected
# node.
g <- graph_from_data_frame(el, directed=F)
plot(g, edge.width=E(g)$dist)

# Community-detection with weights as inverted distance:
between_point_weights <- max(E(g)$dist)-E(g)$dist
comm <- cluster_spinglass(g, spins=2, weights=between_point_weights)
plot(g, vertex.color=comm$membership, edge.width=E(g)$dist, layout = layout_nicely)

# Communities are here
comm
```

In the output graph, you see that all points have a relationship to all other points (since every point has a distance to other points). The distance is visualised as thick lines if the distance is large. The three points close to each other are correctly clustered into the same group. Find the groupings in the `comm` object. Note also how igrpah works with weights and that I invert the weights for algorithmic and visualisation purposes. You can visualise the distances with thick-lines for closeness if you like by using the same weights we sent to the `cluster_spinglass()` which needs high values for closeness (the opposite of the relational distance).

[image]

You can experiment with cutoffs in `spins` with the algorithm here used in order to get the "desired" number of communities, but there is no such thing as an absolute definition of how clustering works; it's up to you to define sensible borders.

To return to the overall question, this network approach would perhaps not make great sense next to other classification algorithms.

Comment: I'm aware that my questions are a bit vague, so I would like to thank you very much for taking the time to answer to this! I agree with most of your point and I will probably stick to the clustering methods. I will however try this approach you proposed and see if I can use it somehow (or something similar). Thanks!